# XSLT to show only unique values for glossary index?

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

This glossary derives the index from the first letter of each entry. I'm trying to work out how to show only the unique values. Have looked into preceding-sibling and position() but cannot seem to find the correct way to. I'm constrained to using XSLT 1.0 and attributes.

glossary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="glossary.xsl"?>
<include>
    <file name="data.xml"/>
</include>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<glossary>
    <entry term="cantaloupe" definition="A kind of melon"/>
    <entry term="banana" definition="A tropical yellow fruit"/>
    <entry term="apple" definition="A red fruit with seeds"/>
    <entry term="orange" definition="An orange citrus fruit"/>  
    <entry term="Cherry"  definition="A red fruit that grows in clusters "/>
    <entry term="cranberry" definition="A sour berry enjoyed at Thanksgiving"/>
    <entry term="avocado"  definition="A mellow fruit enjoyed in guacamole"/>
</glossary>
```

glossary.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <!-- Index: how to show unique values? -->
                <xsl:for-each select="document('data.xml')/glossary/entry" >
                    <xsl:sort select="@term" data-type="text" order="ascending" case-order="upper-first"/> 
                    <xsl:variable name="initial" select="substring(@term,1,1)" />
                    <a href="#{$initial}"><xsl:value-of select="$initial" /></a> |  
                </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- Glossary -->   
                <dl>
                    <xsl:for-each select="document('data.xml')/glossary/entry" >
                        <xsl:sort select="@term" data-type="text" order="ascending" case-order="upper-first"/> 
                        <xsl:variable name="initial" select="substring(@term,1,1)" />
                        <!-- Alphabetical header: how to only the first instance of each letter? -->
                        <a name="{$initial}"><h1><xsl:value-of select="$initial" /></h1></a> 
                        <dt><xsl:apply-templates select="@term"/></dt>
                        <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="@definition"/></dd>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </dl> 
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output so far

a | a | b | c | C | c | o |

a
apple
   A red fruit with seeds
a
avocado
   A mellow fruit enjoyed in guacamole
b
banana
   A tropical yellow fruit
c
cantaloupe
   A kind of melon
C
Cherry
   A red fruit that grows in clusters
 
c
cranberry
   A sour berry enjoyed at Thanksgiving
o
orange
   An orange citrus fruit

---

Desired output

a | b | c | o

a
apple
   A red fruit with seeds

avocado
   A mellow fruit enjoyed in guacamole

b
banana
   A tropical yellow fruit

c
cantaloupe
   A kind of melon

Cherry
   A red fruit that grows in clusters

cranberry
   A sour berry enjoyed at Thanksgiving

o
orange
   An orange citrus fruit

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to use the Muenchian grouping. I can get @JLRishe solution to work but still fiddling with ian-roberts' version. Not sure how to evaluate which is more efficient though. I guess xslt 1.0 is unweildy for this kind of thing. Also - I'm wondering if the downcasing is necessary? Does xsl:sort see upper and lower case as different characters?

Comment: `xsl:sort` sees upper and lowercase as different, but _that's_ not really an issue here. The downcasing is important because (1) the Muenchian grouping techinique would treat them as separate characters if they're not consistently cased and (2) You'll want to have consistent casing in your headers.

Comment: I've read about the Muenchian grouping and I'm grateful to have a working example, so is it the only viable approach? Does XSLT 1.0 have no way then to simply compare the existing initial with the previous one and only show if different? Maybe I'm missing a fundamental limitation of XSLT 1.0 as I'm so new to this...

Comment: Grouping _can_ be done by comparing values against preceding values, but it's not really any cleaner and that approach is discouraged because it is very computationally inefficient, especially if there are a lot of rows in the source data. Earlier this month Dimitre Novatchev commented on a situation where he saw a `preceding-sibling` grouping operation take over 40 minutes, while the Muenchian approach finished in 2 seconds. In Computer Science terms, "Muenchian has O(N) time complexity, while the time complexity of siblings-comparisson grouping is quadratical -- O(N^2)."

Comment: XSLT is not a procedural language, it simply describes how to transform one XML document into another.  Despite its name an `<xsl:for-each>` doesn't necessarily have to be implemented by an XSLT processor as a sequential loop, the processor is free to calculate the values of the various "iterations" in any order or even in parallel in multiple threads, as long as the final output is produced in the correct order (e.g. it could process the elements in document order and then apply the `sort` at the end when outputting the fragments).

Comment: You can use XPath expressions to compare the current element within a `for-each` with its own preceding siblings _in document order_, but there's no way to access the "previous" element _in the ordering imposed by the `<xsl:sort>`_

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes, that is true, but it is possible to achieve (very inefficient) sorted grouping with something like `<xsl:for-each select="item[not(. = preceding-sibling::item)]"><xsl:sort select="." />...</xsl:for-each>` Can't figure off the top of my head how to do that with partial values though, so that might not even be an option in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a grouping problem and in XSLT 1.0, the established way to do grouping is to use Muenchian Grouping. Unfortunately, your scenario requires finding the lower-case of characters on top of that, and that's a bit messy in XSLT 1.0.

Nonetheless, I've produced a solution and it goes as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" 
              encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kEntryInitial" match="entry/@term"
           use="translate(substring(., 1, 1), 
             'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
             'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <!-- Jump into the data.xml DOM so that keys work -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('data.xml')/glossary" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/glossary">
    <!-- Select terms with distinct initials (case invariant) -->
    <xsl:variable name="termsByDistinctInitial"
                  select="entry/@term[generate-id() = 
                             generate-id(key('kEntryInitial', 
                                            translate(substring(., 1, 1), 
                                            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                                            'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]" />

    <!-- Header -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$termsByDistinctInitial" mode="header">
      <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <!-- Glossary -->
    <dl>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$termsByDistinctInitial" mode="main">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </dl>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@term" mode="header">
    <xsl:variable name="initial">
      <xsl:call-template name="ToLower">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring(., 1, 1)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>

    <a href="#{$initial}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$initial" />
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text> |</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@term" mode="main">
    <xsl:variable name="initial">
      <xsl:call-template name="ToLower">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="substring(., 1, 1)" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <a name="{$initial}">
      <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="$initial" />
      </h1>
    </a>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kEntryInitial', $initial)/.." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <dt>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@term"/>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@definition"/>
    </dd>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="ToLower">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($value, 1, 1), 
                      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
                      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your input XML, this produces the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body><a href="#a">a</a> |<a href="#b">b</a> |<a href="#c">c</a> |<a href="#o">o</a>
    <dl><a name="a"><h1>a</h1></a><dt>apple</dt>
      <dd>A red fruit with seeds</dd>
      <dt>avocado</dt>
      <dd>A mellow fruit enjoyed in guacamole</dd><a name="b"><h1>b</h1></a><dt>banana</dt>
      <dd>A tropical yellow fruit</dd><a name="c"><h1>c</h1></a><dt>cantaloupe</dt>
      <dd>A kind of melon</dd>
      <dt>Cherry</dt>
      <dd>A red fruit that grows in clusters </dd>
      <dt>cranberry</dt>
      <dd>A sour berry enjoyed at Thanksgiving</dd><a name="o"><h1>o</h1></a><dt>orange</dt>
      <dd>An orange citrus fruit</dd>
    </dl>
  </body>
</html>
```

One thing I'd suggest considering is using a simple XSLT to "prep" your glossary with initials:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="initial">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(@term, 1, 1),
                                'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces:

```
<glossary>
  <entry initial="c" term="cantaloupe" definition="A kind of melon" />
  <entry initial="b" term="banana" definition="A tropical yellow fruit" />
  <entry initial="a" term="apple" definition="A red fruit with seeds" />
  <entry initial="o" term="orange" definition="An orange citrus fruit" />
  <entry initial="c" term="Cherry" definition="A red fruit that grows in clusters " />
  <entry initial="c" term="cranberry" definition="A sour berry enjoyed at Thanksgiving" />
  <entry initial="a" term="avocado" definition="A mellow fruit enjoyed in guacamole" />
</glossary>
```

then if you use this prepped version as the glossary, the main XSLT can be rid of all those ugly `translate()` functions and becomes a lot cleaner:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" 
              encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kEntryInitial" match="entry/@initial" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <!-- Jump into the data.xml DOM so that keys work -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('data2.xml')/glossary" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/glossary">
    <!-- Select terms with distinct initials (case invariant) -->
    <xsl:variable name="termsByDistinctInitial"
                  select="entry/@initial[generate-id() = 
                             generate-id(key('kEntryInitial', .)[1])]" />

    <!-- Header -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$termsByDistinctInitial" mode="header">
      <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <!-- Glossary -->
    <dl>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$termsByDistinctInitial" mode="main">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="text" order="ascending" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </dl>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@initial" mode="header">
    <a href="#{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </a>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text> |</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@initial" mode="main">
    <a name="{.}">
      <h1>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </h1>
    </a>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kEntryInitial', .)/.." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <dt>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@term"/>
    </dt>
    <dd>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@definition"/>
    </dd>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, the final output is the same as the first example.  If your XSLT processor supports the `node-set()` function, it's also possible to do both of these processing steps in a single XSLT.

Answer (score 2):

The technique you need is called *Muenchian grouping*.  First define a *key* that groups entry elements by the downcased first letter of their term

```
<xsl:key name="entryByInitial" match="entry" use="translate(substring(@term, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
```

Then you use a trick with `generate-id` to extract just the *first* element that matches each key

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('data.xml')">
  <!-- iterate over the "groups" to build the top links -->
  <xsl:for-each select="glossary/entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('entryByInitial', translate(substring(@term, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(@term, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:variable name="initial" select="translate(substring(@term, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
    <!-- insert a leading | before all but the first link -->
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"> | </xsl:if>
    <a href="#{$initial}"><xsl:value-of select="$initial" /></a>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <!-- iterate over the groups again -->
  <xsl:for-each select="glossary/entry[generate-id() = generate-id(key('entryByInitial', translate(substring(@term, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(@term, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:variable name="initial" select="translate(substring(@term, 1, 1), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
    <a name="{$initial}"><h1><xsl:value-of select="$initial" /></h1></a>
    <dl>
      <!-- apply templates for all entries with this key value -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('entryByInitial', $initial)">
        <xsl:sort select="translate(@term, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </dl>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and define a separate template

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
  <dt><xsl:apply-templates select="@term"/></dt>
  <dd><xsl:apply-templates select="@definition"/></dd>
</xsl:template>
```